# Biblatex: `\textcitedelim` redefinition ignored using biblatex-apa style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

Using the `biblatex` citation style `apa`, the modification to the command `\textcitedelim`:

```
\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addspace{und}\addspace}
```

is ignored. Removing `biblatex-apa` as style, everything seems to work fine.

- Any suggestion how to get the desired behavior, i.e. that the last and second-to-last entry of a `\textcite{key1, key2}` are separated by an "und" instead of a comma?

A MWE might help:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber%
           ,style=apa%
           ,maxcitenames=5%
           ,uniquename=full%
           ,sortcites%
           ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\textcitedelim}{\addspace{und}\addspace}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@incollection{Klieme,
    author = {Klieme, E.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {2001},
}
@article{Lipowsky,
    author = {Lipowsky, F.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {2009},
}
@book{Clausen,
    author = {Clausen, M.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {1998},
} 
@book{Kunter,
    author = {Kunter, M.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {2005},
}
@mvbook{Olszewski,
    author = {Olszewski, J.},
    title = {Titel},
    year = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}

\begin{document}
Während \textcite{Klieme,Lipowsky} keine Zusammenhänge nachweisen konnten,
fanden \textcite{Clausen,Kunter,Olszewski} einen signifikanten Zusammenhang.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Mac OSX 10.10.5, LuaTeX Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015) (rev 5238), biblatex v3.0, biblatex-apa v6.7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` does not use  `\textcitedelim`, but `\compcitedelim` here, so we need

```
\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey{\addspace\bibstring{and}}{\addcomma}\space}
```

instead. We have to do the split for the `final` delimiter ourselves here, as there is no `\finalcompcitedelim`.

If you want that change to be limited to `\textcite`, move the redefinition to the pre-code hook

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\textcite}
  {\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey{\addspace\bibstring{and}}{\addcomma}\space}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{textcite}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:post}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{german}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber%
           ,style=apa%
           ,maxcitenames=5%
           ,uniquename=full%
           ,sortcites%
           ]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\compcitedelim}{\iflastcitekey{\addspace\bibstring{and}}{\addcomma}\space}%

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Während \textcite{sigfridsson,worman} keine Zusammenhänge nachweisen konnten,
fanden \textcite{geer,cicero,wilde} einen signifikanten Zusammenhang.
\end{document}
```

[image]